# How to Create a Dynamic CGPoint** array

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cgpoint

I have a few maps (tilemaps made with Tiled QT) and I would like to create a CGpoint **array based on the objects groups of those maps (I call them Waypoints).

Each maps can have a few set of waypoints that I call path.

```
//Create the first dimension
int nbrOfPaths = [[self.tileMap objectGroups] count];
CGPoint **pathArray = malloc(nbrOfPaths * sizeof(CGPoint *));
```

Then for the second dimension

```
//Create the second dimension
int pathCounter = 0;
while ((path = [self.tileMap objectGroupNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Path%d", pathCounter]])) {
    int nbrOfWpts = 0;
    while ((waypoint = [path objectNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wpt%d", nbrOfWpts]])) {
        nbrOfWpts++;
    }
    pathArray[pathCounter] = malloc(nbrOfWpts * sizeof(CGPoint)); 
    pathCounter++;
}
```

Now I want to fill up the pathArray

```
//Fill the array
pathCounter = 0;
while ((path = [self.tileMap objectGroupNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Path%d", pathCounter]]))
{
    int waypointCounter = 0;
    //Get all the waypoints from the path
    while ((waypoint = [path objectNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wpt%d", waypointCounter]]))
    {
        pathArray[pathCounter][waypointCounter].x = [[waypoint valueForKey:@"x"] intValue];
        pathArray[pathCounter][waypointCounter].y = [[waypoint valueForKey:@"y"] intValue];
        NSLog(@"x : %f & y : %f",pathArray[pathCounter][waypointCounter].x,pathArray[pathCounter][waypointCounter].y);
        waypointCounter++;
    }

    pathCounter++;
}
```

When I NSLog(@"%@",pathArray), it shows me the entire pathArray will the x and y.

HOWEVER **2 problems**  :

- The y value is never correct (the x value is correct and my tilemap.tmx is correct too)

  ```
  <object name="Wpt0" x="-18" y="304"/>  <-- I get x : -18 and y :336 with NSLog
  <object name="Wpt1" x="111" y="304"/>  <-- I get x : 111 and y :336
  <object name="Wpt2" x="112" y="207"/>  <-- I get x : 112 and y :433
  ```
- I get a EX_BAD_ACCESS at the end of the NSLog

**EDIT**
Thank you about the NSLog(%@) concerning CGPoint.
However, I get the y value with this line (in the ugly loop):

```
NSLog(@"x : %f & y : %f",pathArray[pathCounter][waypointCounter].x,pathArray[pathCounter][waypointCounter].y);
```

Comment: Your code looks right, could you show the exact call to `NSLog`? You aren't trying to print `pathArray` with a `%@` specifier, right? Because that specifier is for objects, and `pathArray` is a C array. You need to go through it using the same two-nested-loops arrangement that you used for filling it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't NSLog CGPoint like that because it is not an object.  `%@` expects an objective c object to send a `description` message to.

Secondly, you can use an `NSValue` wrapper and then use `NSMutableArray` as you would with any other object.  Is there a reason you don't want to do that?  You can add arrays inside other arrays as you are doing.

Comment: I deleted the NSLog(%@), no EXC_BAD_ACCESS but still this y value problem. Actually, concerning the NSValue : I come from C++ and still don't understand how the NSMutableArray with addObject and stuff work. If you can give me some nice and clean example for 2d/3d array =) Thank you !

Comment: NSMutableArray in obj-c works like a vector in C++, except instead of push_back, you use addObject and instead of pop you use removeObject / removeObjectAtIndex, removeLastObject etc.

Comment: Ok, I tried to do it in Obj-C instead of plain C. This is what I get : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698682/how-to-dynamically-create-a-2d-nsmutablearray-with-loops

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first problem:

> The y value is never correct (the x value is correct and my tilemap.tmx is correct too)

Have you noticed that if you add the y values from tile map and from NSLog they always add up to 640? Then you better check if tilemap y-coordinate is top-to-bottom as oppose to CGPoint's bottom-to-top. Then you can always do 640 - y to convert the y-coordinate between the two coordinate systems.

Comment: Woah ! Great ! Actually y is correctly read from the tilemap.tmx. It is just NSLog going nut =) So there shouldn't be any problems if I use the y values without doing anything to them in the rest of my code (like adding a sprite on the x/y coord)