# How to dynamically create a 2d NSMutableArray with loops

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray

I made an original post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11685637/how-to-create-a-dynamic-cgpoint-array/11685806#11685806)

At first, I tried to fill up a CGPoint **allPaths.

With the first dimension being "a path" and the second dimension being "the waypoint". And I get a CGPoint out of this.

For example : allPaths[0][2] would give me the CGPoint of the first path, third waypoint.

I successfully did it in plain C with nasty loops. And now I am trying to do the same thing in Obj-C with NSMutableArrays.

Here is my code :

```
CCTMXObjectGroup *path;
NSMutableDictionary *waypoint;

int pathCounter = 0;
int waypointCounter = 0;

NSMutableArray *allPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *allWaypointsForAPath = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Get all the Paths
while ((path = [self.tileMap objectGroupNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Path%d", pathCounter]]))
{
    waypointCounter = 0;
    //Empty all the data of the waypoints (so I can reuse it)
    [allWaypointsForAPath removeAllObjects];

    //Get all the waypoints from the path
    while ((waypoint = [path objectNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wpt%d", waypointCounter]]))
    {
        int x = [[waypoint valueForKey:@"x"] intValue];
        int y = [[waypoint valueForKey:@"y"] intValue];

        [allWaypointsForAPath addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)]];
        //Get to the next waypoint
        waypointCounter++;
    }

    //Add the waypoints of the path to the list of paths
    [allPaths addObject:allWaypointsForAPath];

    //Get to the next path
    pathCounter++;
}
```

My actual problem is that all paths in allPaths are equal to the last one. (all the first paths are overrided with the last one)

I know that it is because of this line [allPaths addObject:allWaypointsForAPath].

Yet, how should I do it ?

Comment: If you are using "objectNamed" and inner indexing for the array, why not just switch it to an NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: Actually, I want to keep the NSMutableArray because I work with index number not with key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I think I found out something !
Not sure about memory issue, but I guess the garbage collector should work ?

Actually, I just have to declaremy NSMutableArray *allWaypointsForAPath in the loop like this :

```
int pathCounter = 0;
int waypointCounter = 0;

NSMutableArray *allPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Get all the PathZ
while ((path = [self.tileMap objectGroupNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Path%d", pathCounter]]))
{
    waypointCounter = 0;
    NSMutableArray *allWaypointsForAPath = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    //Get all the waypoints from the path
    while ((waypoint = [path objectNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wpt%d", waypointCounter]]))
    {
        int x = [[waypoint valueForKey:@"x"] intValue];
        int y = [[waypoint valueForKey:@"y"] intValue];
        [allWaypointsForAPath addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(x, y)]];
        //Get to the next waypoint
        waypointCounter++;
    }

    [allPaths addObject:allWaypointsForAPath];
    //Get to the next path
    pathCounter++;
}
```

Comment: Yes, do you understand why?  Because in your original code you are just reusing the same array [i.e. same pointer] (so obviously, all of your instances will point to the same location in memory in the end ^^).  This code makes a new pointer each time.  Be careful with your terms though because there is no garbage collection on iOS.  ARC should do its job (I assume it is enabled?) and release any objects that aren't used.

Comment: Yes I now understand. I have enabled ARC and I hope it will free the memory correctly ! =) (I guess I will repost a question if I get memory issues)